# How to get the AppDomain.CurrentDomain for WP 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

When i getting the app Domain of my windows phone 8 app i did this

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName
```

but, when i try do that in Windows phone 8.1 cant recognize the class App Domain, so, how to get the App Domain name for my application ?